# How to change default header of palette in wicket?

Tags: wicket

I want to change headers of palette in wicket (i.e, Available and Selected ). Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either provide custom values for the resource keys or completely override the factory methods: https://github.com/apache/wicket/blob/ce66c242ad83266a4f5c01363b4b446138b054e9/wicket-extensions/src/main/java/org/apache/wicket/extensions/markup/html/form/palette/Palette.java#L284-L300